# How do i put a line under the page that is currently being viewed on the nav bar?

Tags: html, css

I have a nav which is this code:

```
<div id="nav" class="ten columns">
<ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So heres the nav at the moment: About   Portfolio   Blog   Contact

How do i put a line under the page that is currently being veiwed? So if the user clicks on Portfolio, then the nav bar will look like:

About Portfolio Blog Contact

```
     ________
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, this is implemented using server-side software to add a class to the nav item that is selected. Then, you style that class so it has a bottom border. You can set it up so that all the pages have a bottom border of the same width, but the border on the selected item is different from the border on the others (which border should at least "appear" to be transparent).

**Edited to include code snippet**

```
<div id="nav" class="ten columns">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
div#nav > ul > li {
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
div#nav > ul > li.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This code put a line underneath all of the nav items? Am i doing something wrong? Simply copied and pasted it in inside

Comment: Maybe its because im not running it on a server yet. And that the hrefs for the links is just "#" at the moment and not real pages

Comment: @jamesjames94 I don't have all the code to work with, so I don't know what color your background is. If your background is white, then the `border-color` on `div#nav > ul > li` should be white; if your background is maroon, then the `border-color` on `div#nav > ul > li` should be maroon. You can set `border-color` on `div#nav > ul > li` to `transparent`, but I recall that having issues with browser-compatibility.

Comment: Do i have to put the class active on all the nav items?

Comment: @jamesjames94 No, you don't. Put the `active` class on only the active item. That way, the border under the `active` item will distinguish it from the rest.

Answer (score 1):

add a class active to the current list element.

```
<div id="nav" class="ten columns">
<ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#" >Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

.active {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

If your site is a static site you will have to do it manually, otherwise you can take advantage of the CMS pre-built classes.

Comment: Is there a way i can space the line from the word more?

Comment: You can use the border-bottom solution, then add the class to the <a> element instead and use padding-bottom : 10px or whatever value suits you

Answer (score 0):

I do it automatically on static sites!

I use javascript and jQuery to get the document URL. I then search each `href` in my menu and add a class to those that match the document URL. In this case, the class added is `.activestyle` which can be styled any way you like.

```
var urlname = (document.URL.substring(document.URL.lastIndexOf("\/")+1));

$('#menu ul li').each(function () {
if( $(this).html().indexOf('"'+urlname+'"')!=-1 ){
        $(this).children('a').addClass("activestyle");
}
});
```

This is a particularly good way of solving the problem as your menu stays the same site wide which is better for site-wide updates.

Comment: Please review the code snippet above. All the links have the same `href`: `#`. This answer might work well in other situations, certainly, but not in the situation described above.

Comment: At times you have to make assumptions about a question. I'm presuming at a later date, @jamesjames94 will populate his menu with the correct hrefs. eg about.html, portfolio.html etc. I use this all the time. Works like a charm

Comment: Even if his hrefs are all the same, it's a elegant solution to the problem, `href` could be substituted for another distinguishing factor in the html of each menu item.